# How to Remove Dependable Links when deleting item using item.Delete()

Tags: link-manager, broken-links, sitecore-mvc

We are programmatically removing items using item.Delete() in C#. Deleted items that were linked to other items are appearing as broken link
[image]

When manually deleting in Sitecore we get options like below img
[image]

But when removed from code it not removing links.How to remove links programmatically before deleting item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a Sitecore item programmatically using the `item.Delete()` method in C#, any references to the deleted item will remain in the system, resulting in broken links. To remove these broken links, you can use the Sitecore `LinkDatabase`.

Here is an example of how you can remove broken links to a deleted item:

```csharp
var itemToDelete = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/path/to/item");

// Delete the item
itemToDelete.Delete();

// Get the item's ID
var itemId = itemToDelete.ID;

// Remove all references to the deleted item from the link database
var links = Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase.GetItemReferrers(itemToDelete, false);
foreach (var link in links)
{
    var item = link.GetSourceItem();
    if (item != null)
    {
        using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
        {
            var field = item.Fields[link.SourceFieldID];
            if (field != null)
            {
                var value = field.Value;
                if (Sitecore.StringUtil.Contains(value, itemId.ToString()))
                {
                    value = value.Replace(itemId.ToString(), string.Empty);
                    item.Editing.BeginEdit();
                    field.Value = value;
                    item.Editing.EndEdit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, We used `Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase.GetItemReferrers(itemToDelete, false)` to get all the items that refer to the deleted item.
This should remove all broken links to the deleted item from the link database.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore runs a code similar to this snippet:

```
public void RemoveItemLinks(Item targetItem, bool removeCloneLinks)
{
    foreach (Item child in targetItem.Children)
        RemoveItemLinks(child, removeCloneLinks);

    foreach (ItemLink referrer in Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(targetItem))
    {
        if (removeCloneLinks || !(referrer.SourceFieldID == FieldIDs.Source) && !(referrer.SourceFieldID == FieldIDs.SourceItem))
        {
            Item sourceItem = referrer.GetSourceItem();
            if (sourceItem != null && !ID.IsNullOrEmpty(referrer.SourceFieldID))
                RemoveLink(sourceItem, referrer);
        }
    }
}

private static void RemoveLink(Item version, ItemLink itemLink)
{
    CustomField field = FieldTypeManager.GetField(version.Fields[itemLink.SourceFieldID]);

    if (field == null)
        return;

    using (new SecurityDisabler())
    {
        version.Editing.BeginEdit();
        field.RemoveLink(itemLink);
        version.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar kind of thing in my project and here is the approach I used.

Created a method to pass the target item like below.

```
public void RemoveLinksofTargetItem(Item targetItem)
{
    var links = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(targetItem);

    foreach (var link in links)
    {
            Item sourceItem = link.GetSourceItem();
            if (sourceItem != null && !ID.IsNullOrEmpty(link.SourceFieldID))
                RemoveLink(sourceItem, link);
    }
}
```

Created a method to remove links.

```
private void RemoveLink(Item item, ItemLink itemLink)
{
    CustomField field = FieldTypeManager.GetField(item.Fields[itemLink.SourceFieldID]);
    if (field != null)
    {
        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            item.Editing.BeginEdit();
            field.RemoveLink(itemLink);
            item.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

I referred to this code by extracting the `Sitecore.Client` DLL that has this logic on choosing the Remove Links as shown in the image in your question.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the link field and then remove it. Try out the below code.

1. Get the item links

```
ItemLink[] itemLinks = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(item);
```

2. Programmatically find and remove item links. You need to loop them to remove links.

```
ItemLink[] itemLinks = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath));

foreach (ItemLink link in itemLinks)
{
     Sitecore.Data.Items.Item linkItem = Context.Database.GetItem(link.SourceItemID);
     if (linkItem == null) continue;

     Field field = linkItem.Fields[link.SourceFieldID];
     if (field == null) continue;

     CustomField customField = FieldTypeManager.GetField(field);
     if (customField == null) continue;

     linkItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
     customField.RemoveLink(link);
     linkItem.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

Hope it helps!